# Are SO and InPrivate Filtering supposed to work well together?

Tags: support, jquery

IE8 has an adblocker built in. It is called [InPrivate Filtering](http://www.mrfixitonline.com/viewtopic.php?t=8089) (not to be confused with InPrivate browsing a.k.a. porn mode). I have InPrivate Filtering on by default, and it did not interfere with SO before.

Recently, something changed, and I cannot do anything until I switch InPrivate Filtering off. I guess there was a change in SO script or a new ad arrived. Anybody else experiencing this? Any ideas how to fix it? Is it (should it be) a concern for SO developers?

Comment: I'll just save everyone some time: "OMG IE SUX USE TEH FIREFOX!"  Isn't it nice to just get that out of the way?

Comment: It's not porn mode, it's Christmas gift shopping mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it says it blocks '3rd party content'. jQuery is now stored on Google's servers which could be considered as 3rd party content, I suppose. This is most likely the root cause of your error. If not, then you're going to have to be more specific about what 'I cannot do anything' means.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The moment I allowed jQuery, everything start working again. (By "working" and "do" I meant scripting events, thinks like upvoting, commenting and so on.)